# Silverlight combobox with checkboxes items

Tags: silverlight

I am facing some troubles creating a Silverlight custom control - a combobox with checkboxes.
Do we have something out of the box to do this?

Comment: The short answer is no.  Please provide more details, why would you want such a thing?

Comment: I have to have the users select multiple options from a drop down list with visual guidance using checkboxes.. Do we have 3rd party controls that do it? How do i do it otherwise?

Comment: In that case the ComboBox is not the right tool for the job.  A list box hosted by a popup control would prehaps be a better candidate.

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyWJones. Any pointers on how do I do that? I am a newbie to SL UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(sorry for my bad english)

If you want to display checkboxes as items of a comboBox, a simple DataTemplate shoud work:

```
        <ComboBox Name="combo" >
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Text}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

Now on your code behind create an ObservableCollection<CheckItem> ChekItem is a basic class:

```
public class CheckItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

and associate it to your comboBox ItemsSource. 
If you want to know what items are checked, is simple:

```
var checkedItems = myList.Where(i => i.IsChecked == true);
```

Comment: Hi @Leo, How do you control the selected record what is displayed on the Combobox. I want to show custom message say "Multiple" or "All" based on selection of the items using hte checkboxes..

Comment: @whihathac, you can't use a ComboBox in this case then, ComboBox only has SelectedItem not SelectedItems. You should consider AnthonyWJones' solution. Also, showing "Multiple" is just not obvious, the user has to actually click to open it in order to see what has been selected.

Comment: Thanks @Xin, thats the requirement :) What alternative do you suggest to showing instead of Multiple?

Comment: @whihathac, it all depends on how many items do you have in the list, how long the text is and how big this control can be. You can create a custom control just similar to the look of a combobox, when the user expands it, it shows a popup control which contains a listbox. regarding the display text, if you have enough space you can display the selected item names separated by ",", e.g. "item one, item two, item three", if there are not enough space, you might consider display something like "item one, item two and 4 more". Not sure exactly what you need though, just throw you some ideas. :)

Comment: Thanks @Xin. Can I extend the current combo box control to do what you are suggesting? Cn you point me to some tutorials that can help me with this?

Comment: If you got the combobox working with my sample, now your data is bounded to the observablelist you created - so you do not need "SelectedItems" on the combobox. It doesn't even make sense for you since you do not want to get the combobox selection but the checked items.

One easy way to show the checked items would be to bind a textblock with the same ObservableCollection and use a converter to join the checked items on a string like "Item1, Item3"

Look here, it is not beautiful and kind of a hack but give the results you are looking for: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/427024/temp/so/combo/test.html

Comment: @Leo That looks great! Are you using a combobox for the drop down or its a plain button? Can you share the code as answer :)

Comment: @whihathac I'm using a combobox for the dropdown but you could use a button+listbox or ItemsControl... there are multiple ways to solve this problem :) - As I said the code is a bit of hack but get the job done ;) - here it is: https://github.com/leo-mck/ComboCheckBox